# PHP Function stopped with PHP 7.4

Tags: php, php-7.4

I used to use this function inside a form on my site.

```php
<input
  id="domainPageLimit" 
  name="domainPageLimit" 
  class="" 
  type="text" 
  value="<?= display_form_value($domain['domainPageLimit'], ($_SESSION['form_data']['domainPageLimit'] ?: null )) ?>"
  <?= admin_edit_only() ?>
/>
```

My function display_form_value() would pull data if it existed in the database for this particular user.  The $_SESSION['form_data'][domainPageLimit] was the info the user submitted on a form, in case they were sent back due to validation errors.
What I wanted to happen was if the display_form_value() was not set and the form_data was not set, it would return the value of NULL to the form to eliminate the "variable not set" error PHP was throwing.

With PHP 7.3, it was working fine.
With PHP 7.4, I receive this error in the browser: "Trying to access array offset on value of type null".

Has the (value ? value ?: value) function changed from 7.3 to 7.4?

Comment: Use `??` instead of `?:`

Comment: Shoot, is that all it is?  What is that operator called?  I can never seem to find it.

Comment: [Null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op)

Comment: FYI, the `?:` [ternary shorthand](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) is still valid

Comment: It's valid, but I think it doesn't work with nested array indexing when the outer reference is null. So you get that error when `$_SESSION['form_data']` is missing.

Comment: Are you sure your parentheses are right? Your ternary expression evaluation is passed as the 2nd arg to `display_form_value()` but that doesn't match up with your description

Comment: @Phil I think he may be confused about where the error is happening.

Comment: Is the error happening on the line that calls the function or inside the function?

Comment: @Barmar I think you're right. PHP 7 did get more strict on array access so their code is probably correct (as far as parentheses go)

Comment: This is the full error showing up in the browser: "Notice:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /home/username/public_html/designer/pages_common/faq_edit.inc.php on line 83".  It would seem to me the error is occurring on the line that calls my function.